# Building Outdoor Concrete Sculpture

Tags: sculpting

For building an outdoor public park sculpture (1.25 times life-sized, containing several figures) would it be better to build a metal frame, wrapped in mesh, covered in concrete;

Or, would it be better to make a model and create a mould and pour concrete into that?

The first option (hollow) or the second option (solid)? For a public park. Is there an obvious choice, or would each option have equal advantages and disadvantages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exposed to the public it will take a lot of abuse . So it needs to be as strong as possible. Use the hollow mold but put a steel rebar armature /core into it before you pour in the concrete. Use lots of rebar and lots of cement in the concrete. I have seen solid concrete benches destroyed in Cook Co IL and other places.